# PHP table data convert to downloadable PDF --- dat doesn't pass to table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

All data display in the table when selecting the parameter and post it from the form. But when data convert to pdf, data value doesn't pass to pdf table. But if I remove $Parameter value from

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        id, 
        sensor, 
        location, 
        Parameter, 
        Value, 
        Reading_Time 
    FROM readings 
    WHERE Parameter='$Parameter' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Here and set `Parameter ='Temperature'` or any other variable. Code works fine.
I can't find why data doesn't pass to pdf file?
Can anyone help me with this?

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>SoftAOX | Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="s" method="post">
            <br><label>Parameter</label><br>
            <select name="parameter">
                <option value="">None</option>
                <option value="Rain">Rain</option>
                <option value="Temperature">Temperature</option>
                <option value="Humidity">Humidity</option>
                <option value="Pressure">Pressure</option>

            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
        </form>

        <?php
      
        $type="";
      if(isset($_POST['parameter'])) {
      //echo "selected parameter: ".$_POST['parameter'];
      $type=$_POST['parameter']; }  

function fetch_data()  {     
      global $type;
      $output = '';  
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "example_esp_data"); 
      $Parameter=$type; 
      $sql = "SELECT id, sensor, location, Parameter, Value, Reading_Time FROM readings WHERE Parameter='$Parameter' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {       
                $t = $row["Reading_Time"]+19800;
                                $row_Time = date("j-m-Y H:i:s",$t); 
                 $output .= '<tr>  
                                <td>'.$row["sensor"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["location"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["Parameter"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["Value"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row_Time .'</td> 
                            </tr>  
                                '; 
            }  
      
    return   $output; 
            
 } 

    if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h4 align="center">Generate HTML Table Data To PDF From MySQL Database Using TCPDF In PHP</h4><br /> 
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
           <tr>  
                <th>Sensor</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Parameter</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Reading_Time</th>
           </tr>  
      ';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      ob_end_clean();
      $obj_pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I'); 
     
 }  
 ?>



        <br />
        <div class="container">
            <h4 align="center"> <?php echo $Parameter .""."Weather Data" ; ?></h4><br />
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-success" value="Download" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sensor</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Parameter</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>Reading_Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php  
                     echo fetch_data(); 
                     
                     ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>






    <?php ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        ini_set("track_errors", 1);
        ini_set("html_errors", 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        require './Database.php'; 
?>
```

Comment: What is the content of your `$content` variable just before you pass it to TCPDF?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input. Start by refactoring the code and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: You are defining a $type and assigning that to $Parameter. As I see $Parameter is empty when forming the $sql. 

echo $Parameter; before $sql forming to check the $Parameter value.

Comment: Thank you sir.i tryed but still data doesn't pass to pdf.